# Attaching shadow DOM to a custom element removes error, but why?

Tags: html, shadow-dom, custom-element

Per the [custom element specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance),

> The element must not gain any attributes or children, as this violates the expectations of consumers who use the `createElement` or `createElementNS` methods.

Both Firefox and Chrome correctly throw an error in this situation. However, when attaching a shadow DOM, no error is present (in either browser).

Firefox:

> NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported

Chrome:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have children

*Without* shadow DOM

```js
function createElement(tag, ...children) {
  let root;

  if (typeof tag === 'symbol') {
    root = document.createDocumentFragment();
  } else {
    root = document.createElement(tag);
  }

  children.forEach(node => root.appendChild(node));

  return root;
}

customElements.define(
  'x-foo',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.appendChild(
        createElement(
          Symbol(),
          createElement('div'),
        ),
      );
    }
  },
);

createElement('x-foo');
```

*With* shadow DOM

```js
function createElement(tag, ...children) {
  let root;

  if (typeof tag === 'symbol') {
    root = document.createDocumentFragment();
  } else {
    root = document.createElement(tag);
  }

  children.forEach(node => root.appendChild(node));

  return root;
}

customElements.define(
  'x-foo',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      // it doesn't matter if this is open or closed
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' }).appendChild(
        createElement(
          Symbol(),
          createElement('div'),
        ),
      );
    }
  },
);

createElement('x-foo');
```

Please note: in order to view the examples, [you need to be using](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1) (at least) one of the following: Firefox 63, Chrome 67, Safari 10.1. Edge is not supported.

My question is as follows:

Is the behavior demonstrated correct, per the specification?

Adding a child node to the root would cause a DOM reflow; how can this be avoided without a shadow DOM present?

Comment: 1) Because Shadow Tree in not a child, so there's no error to be raised. 2) Yes it's correct per the specs. 3) You could avoid reflow if the custom element has predefined fixed length and width.

Comment: @Supersharp I presume the "expectation" in question is to be given an element and nothing else. Would the shadow DOM not violate that, given that anything can be added to that? It seems odd that I can add children, but only if they're indirect. It's not like it limits access to the children, either, as an open shadow is acceptable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time an element is created it is done through the constructor. But, when the constructor is called there are no children nor any attributes, Those are all added AFTER the component is created.

Even if the element is defined in the HTML page, it is still created by code using the constructor and then the attributes and children are added by the code that is parsing the DOM in the HTML page.

When the constructor is called there are no children and you can not add them since the DOM parser may be adding them as soon as the constructor is finished. The same rule applies for the attributes.

Currently there is no way to specify shadowDOM or shadowDOM children except through JS code. The DOM parser will not add any children to the shadowDOM.

So according to the spec it is illegal to access, change or do anything with attributes or children in the constructor. But, since there is no way for the DOM parser to add anything into a components shadowDOM that is not illegal.

I have gotten around this problem when not using shadowDOM by using an internal template element that is created in the constructor and then placed as a child once the `connectedCallback` is called.

```js
// Class for `<test-el>`
class TestEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('constructor');
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = '<div class="name"></div>';
    this.root = template.content;
    this.rendered = false;
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['name'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
      console.log('attributeChangedCallback', newVal);
      this.root.querySelector('.name').textContent = newVal;
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('connectedCallback');
    if (!this.rendered) {
      this.rendered = true;
      this.appendChild(this.root);
      this.root = this;
    }
  }

  // `name` property
  get name() {
    return this.getAttribute('name');
  }
  set name(value) {
    console.log('set name', value);
    if (value == null) { // Check for null or undefined
      this.removeAttribute('name');
    }
    else {
      this.setAttribute('name', value)
    }
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('test-el', TestEl);

const moreEl = document.getElementById('more');
const testEl = document.getElementById('test');
setTimeout(() => {
testEl.name = "Mummy";
  const el = document.createElement('test-el');
  el.name = "Frank N Stein";
  moreEl.appendChild(el);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<test-el id="test" name="Dracula"></test-el>
<hr/>
<div id="more"></div>
```

This code creates a template in the constructor and uses `this.root` to reference it.
Once `connectedCallback` is called I insert the template into the DOM and change `this.root` to point to `this` so that all of my references to elements still work.

This is a quick way to allow your component to always be able to keep its children correct without using shadowDOM and only placing the template into the DOM as children once `connectedCalback` is called.

Comment: "But, since there is no way for the DOM parser to add anything into a components shadowDOM that is not illegal. ← That's the line that made me (mostly) understand why. No, you can't touch the DOM, but that literally _isn't_ the DOM, it's a shadow DOM.

Comment: I use this method as well, but it is difficult for me to understand why you need to "change this.root to point to this"?  Also when I create this programmatically and add ti to DOM I don't have test-el anymore just its content, is that expected?

Comment: The reason you have to change `this.root` to point to `this` is so the `this.root` is always pointing to the container. Before the `connectedCallback` is called the first time `this.root` is pointing to the `template.content`. Once you move that content into the DOM your `this.root` has to change with it because the `template.content` will no longer hold the html.

Answer (score 3):

> The element must not gain any attributes or children, as this violates the expectations of consumers who use the createElement or createElementNS methods.

The "expectations" of `createElement()` is to be given a empty element (without HTML attributes, or children HTML elements), like any other standard HTML element that you create with `createElement()`.

Therefore the impact of adding the Custom Elements to the HTML and DOM specification (and as a consequence, on the HTML engine implementation) is somehow limited.

This restriction doesn't apply to the Shadow DOM because it was not part of the specs before. This won't alter the above expectations. Hence the "odd" difference between the normal DOM tree and the Shadow DOM tree, you're right.

Also, the ability to add a Shadow DOM in the `contructor()` and not a light DOM, ensures that when the elements of the light DOM are added, they will preventively be filtered according to the Shadow DOM template (and event model, if you listen to the `slotchange` event).