# Constructor restrictions for Custom Elements in Web Components

Tags: javascript, web, dom, w3c, custom-element

In the W3C custom elements spec, it is mentioned that within the Custom element constructor:

> The element must not gain any attributes or children, as this violates the expectations of consumers who use the `createElement` or `createElementNS` methods.

I am finding it difficult to understand what expectations are we violating. My initial guess was that using `createElement` to create a custom element does not invoke the Constructor behind the scenes, but that does not seem to be the case based on a proof of concept which I did.

Answer (score 1):

Read the answers **and** comments from this one first:

- [Attaching shadow DOM to a custom element removes error, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180428/attaching-shadow-dom-to-a-custom-element-removes-error-but-why)

Then these

- [Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The result must not have children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181683/failed-to-execute-createelement-on-document-the-result-must-not-have-childr)
- [Deferred setAttribute call in Custom Element constructor causes DOM error. Is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857905/deferred-setattribute-call-in-custom-element-constructor-causes-dom-error-is-it)

Comment: Scrapping my head for quite some time. This answer really helped!